# What type of code is used to create sequence in POSTGRESQL13?

Tags: postgresql

Recently Which datatype is used for generating sequence in postgres13 ?
Creating Sequence separately or Using serial or Identity datatype ?
Which is best and why ?
Also Mapping between datatype is easy ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[As documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createsequence.html) default data type is `bigint` if you don't specify a type.

> The optional clause `AS data_type` specifies the data type of the sequence. [...]  **`bigint` is the default**. The data type determines the default minimum and maximum values of the sequence.

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

However with a current Postgres version it is [recommended](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_serial) to use `identity` columns instead of `serial`

[As documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html#id-1.9.3.85.6.2.18.1.2) you can control the details (data type most importantly) of the underlying sequence when you declare an identity column.